# AngularJS rendering from deeply nested jsonp

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, jsonp

I am new to JSON and also AngularJS. I'm trying to access data elements in a deeply nested remote json file. I can manage to render the whole JSON results in my view. However, I can't seem to target the elements that are in an array deep inside the JSON. It's from Yahoo Currency.

This is my controller and view that renders the entire JSON file:

**controller**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('DataCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.jsonp('https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20json%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Ffinance.yahoo.com%2Fwebservice%2Fv1%2Fsymbols%2Fallcurrencies%2Fquote%3Fformat%3Djson%22&format=jsonp&callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function (data) {

        $scope.data = data;
    });
});
```

**view**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app" >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>LIVE</title>
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="DataCtrl">
  <h1>Live from JSON feed</h1>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="row in data">
      {{ data }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried writing the controller like this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('DataCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.jsonp('https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20json%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Ffinance.yahoo.com%2Fwebservice%2Fv1%2Fsymbols%2Fallcurrencies%2Fquote%3Fformat%3Djson%22&format=jsonp&callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function (data) {
            var pair = { name };
        // $scope.data = data;
        if(data) {
            if (data.results) {
                pair.name = data.results.list.resources[0].resource.fields.name;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

But that doesn't work. Here is the JSON (partial) .. I'm trying to access the "name", "price", and "utctimestamp" fields for each resource:

```
{
  "query": {
    "count": 1,
    "created": "2015-11-07T05:42:03Z",
    "lang": "en-US",
    "diagnostics": {
      "publiclyCallable": "true",
      "url": {
        "execution-start-time": "0",
        "execution-stop-time": "23",
        "execution-time": "23",
        "content": "http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote?format=json"
      },
      "user-time": "25",
      "service-time": "23",
      "build-version": "0.2.311"
    },
    "results": {
      "list": {
        "meta": {
          "type": "resource-list",
          "start": "0",
          "count": "173"
        },
        "resources": [
          {
            "resource": {
              "classname": "Quote",
              "fields": {
                "name": "USD/KRW",
                "price": "1152.994995",
                "symbol": "KRW=X",
                "ts": "1446874620",
                "type": "currency",
                "utctime": "2015-11-07T05:37:00+0000",
                "volume": "0"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "resource": {
              "classname": "Quote",
              "fields": {
                "name": "SILVER 1 OZ 999 NY",
                "price": "0.068046",
                "symbol": "XAG=X",
                "ts": "1446850711",
                "type": "currency",
                "utctime": "2015-11-06T22:58:31+0000",
                "volume": "100"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "resource": {
              "classname": "Quote",
              "fields": {
                "name": "USD/VND",
                "price": "22364.000000",
                "symbol": "VND=X",
                "ts": "1446874620",
                "type": "currency",
                "utctime": "2015-11-07T05:37:00+0000",
                "volume": "0"
              }
            }
          },
    ...
```

For what it's worth, *jsonp* seems to return some kind of xml-looking stuff when I append the **callback=JSON_CALLBACK** to the url, like this:

```
JSON_CALLBACK({"query":{"count":"1","created":"2015-11-07T16:08:29Z","lang":"en-US"},"results":["<list><meta><type>resource-list</type><start>0</start><count>173</count></meta><resources><resource><classname>Quote</classname><fields><name>USD/KRW</name><price>1152.994995</price><symbol>KRW=X</symbol><ts>1446900900</ts><type>currency</type><utctime>2015-11-07T12:55:00+0000</utctime><volume>0</volume></fields></resource></resources><resources><resource><classname>Quote</classname><fields><name>SILVER 1 OZ 999 NY</name><price>0.068046</price><symbol>XAG=X</symbol><ts>1446850711</ts><type>currency</type><utctime>2015-11-06T22:58:31+0000</utctime><volume>100</volume></fields></resource></resources><resources><resource>
...
```

Is there a problem with how I'm using JSONp? I'm getting the data set rendered to my view (above) but it's all in the funky xml syntax. How to go about grabbing the 3 values I need from that to an array and rendering in a `<ul>`??

Comment: Try to use the browser debugger or log to see if you get the response correctly

Comment: @Dvir Thanks. The controller that dumps all  the XML stuff throws no exceptions.  When I try to specify the field (above), I get the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'resources' of undefined
    at app.js:9
    at angular.js:8950
    at deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (angular.js:6846)
    at angular.js:6883
    at Object.$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:8057)
    at Object.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:7922)
    at Object.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:8143)
    at done (angular.js:9170)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:9333)
    at angular.js:9261`

Comment: After the check if data.results add console.log(data.results)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your original controller, you only had problems in the view. It would work if you substitute it by this one:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app" >
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>LIVE</title>
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="DataCtrl">
        <h1>Live from JSON feed</h1>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="res in data.query.results.list.resources">
                {{ res.resource.fields.name }}: {{ res.resource.fields.price }}, {{ res.resource.fields.utctime }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the Plunker using your JSON example: http://plnkr.co/edit/wzF5t9dTZt49n5eq9N1L?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. Like I said I'm new to Angular  (I'm from Rails). I was trying to find a DRYer solution, refining as much as possible in controller. But hey this works!

Comment: Hi, I tend to use the JS code for needed process and the view for access but if you want to simplify the access in the view, I did a little modification so the data gets accessible easily from the view, it's in this plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/wLQEjbSL4wbhA1qDrhUP?p=preview